# Swift MapKit Centers on Bottom vs. Top of Pin

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I'm using the same function call to display a pin & annotation on my map. When I use this on a current location inside of a reverse geocode call, the pin centers on the base of the pin (obscuring the top of the callout). When I call the same code in any other circumstance (such as when using coordinates passed into the view controller), the map centers on the top of the pin (which is what I want). Code below, image just after this. placesData is an object of a custom class PlacesData, that conforms to both: NSObject, MKAnnotation. Thanks in advance!

```
func updateMap() {
    centerMap(mapLocation: (placeData?.coordinate)!, regionRadius: regionRadius)
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotation(self.placeData!)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(self.placeData!, animated: true)
}
```

Also: if significant, here is the code for my function: mapView(_:viewFor:)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifer = "Marker"
    var view: MKPinAnnotationView
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifer) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        dequedView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequedView
    } else {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifer)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .custom)
    }
    return view
}
```

[image: shows two images, one centering on pin base, the other centering on pin head]